# What is the third argument to std::int::to_str_bytes?

Tags: rust

In Rust programming language - I am trying to convert an integer into the string representation and so I write something like:

```
use std::int::to_str_bytes;
...
to_str_bytes(x, 10);
```

...but it says that I have to specify a third argument.The documentation is here: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/int/fn.to_str_bytes.html , but I am not clever enough to understand what it expects as the third argument.

Answer (score 4):

Using `x.to_str()` as in [Njol's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895656/207384) is the straightforward way to get a string representation of an integer. However, `x.to_str()` returns an owned (and therefore heap-allocated) string (`~str`). As long as you don't need to store the resulting string permanently, you can avoid the expense of an extra heap allocation by allocating the string representation on the stack. This is exactly the point of the `std::int::to_str_bytes` function - to provide a temporary string representation of a number.

The third argument, of type `f: |v: &[u8]| -> U`, is a closure that takes a byte slice (I don't think Rust has stack-allocated strings). You use it like this:

```
let mut f = std::io::stdout();
let result = std::int::to_str_bytes(100, 16, |v| {
    f.write(v);
    Some(())
});
```

`to_str_bytes` returns whatever the closure does, in this case `Some(())`.

Answer (score 1):

int seems to implement ToStr: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/to_str/trait.ToStr.html

so you should be able to simply use `x.to_str()` or `to_str(x)`